# How do you test a Wireshark dissector?

Tags: unit-testing, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

When you write a dissector for Wireshark, how do you test it? Looking for the visual output in the UI is not sufficient for a none-trivial protocol.

Is there a good way for unit testing of the dissector?

**EDIT:**

The structure of protocol frames is dynamic. The dissector must somehow interpret the content.

For example if the fifth field is one a byte array follows as sixth field. If it's two you have a double array and if it's three you have to add a zero terminated string.

This usually never happens in a daily work capture. That's why you need a synthetic capture data even with "impossible" content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To test a Wireshark dissector I found this useful:

- Define a set of packets that the dissector should analyse including malformed packets
- Implement the packets as a hex dump
- Define the expected output
- For each packet dump

  - Generate pcap files with `text2pcap`
  - Run the dissector with `tshark`
  - Extract the payload from the PDML output of tshark
  - Compare the XML output with the expected XML output

This can be improved by filtering the XML output since the PDML also includes the packet bytes, what can be annoying if the payload is large or/and complex.

The suggested arguments to the wireshark executables are

```
text2pcap -T 1024,9876 foo.txt foo.pcap
tshark -T pdml -r "foo.pcap"
```

To extract the dissector output it's useful to use an XPATH expression with the .NET CLR class XmlNode. This can be done e.g. this way:

```
XmlNode output = tsharkOutput.SelectSingleNode("packet/proto[@name='foo']");
XmlNodeList refList = referenceDocument.SelectNodes("proto[@name='foo']");
```

Comment: How can you ensure that only the custom dissector you are developing is being loaded by `tshark`? It seems to load plugins just like `wireshark` so there could be other custom plugins in your Global or Personal plugins folders that you'd want to be sure don't affect the output of your test. Also, having to copy the plugin into the plugins folder (and then potentially delete it to clean up) seems unfortunate.

Comment: @phoenix You could use WIRESHARK_RUN_FROM_BUILD_DIRECTORY to avoid problems you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like Scapy or PacketSender to generate test packets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm old fashioned.  A dissector's primary purpose is transforming data to a human readable form, so I tested mine by having humans read it.

I suppose you could do more automated testing by exporting to txt or pdml from `file->export`, or implementing some sort of test wrapper around your plugin DLL.

Comment: You can only check the output of actual data. But you should also test the behavior of the dissector if it gets data that does not fit the current protocol specification, i.e. the next version.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate test data?  The libpcap file format is well documented at http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat

Comment: No. The generation is only one point in testing. More interesting is the output of the dissector.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the output of [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But I have a lot of frames types, frame variantes and want to check behavior with frames containing invalid data. So I need a fixture to provide a set of data and guess how the dissector finds the data and probably re-syncrhonizes if it gets out-of-sync.      One formalized approach would be tsharks pdml output to be compared with a XML pattern. But how do I omit the parts that are not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Just for updating the post.

> Tshark uses the same plugins as Wireshark, and loads them in the same
>   manner. tshark is also used in this way in the Wireshark CI build
>   tests, see the test directory of the Wireshark sources for some test
>   script examples.
>   https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=tree;f=test 
>   - grahamb.

source: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/36721/tshark-for-plugin-testing